# JavaScript use loop for a complex json

Tags: javascript, html, json, nested

I am using `json.data.schedules[0].liveVideoList` , `json.data.schedules[1].liveVideoList`
 , `json.data.schedules[2].liveVideoList`  and so on

Please tell me how can I use loop here to get all path

script.js code

```
var b = location.search.split('b=')[1];

$.get(
    "index2.php",
    { "b": b },
    function (data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);

        $.each(json.data.schedules[0].liveVideoList, function (i, v) {
            var str = v.thumbnailUrl.split("vi/").pop();

            var datee = v.publishDate.slice(0, 9);
            var timee = v.publishDate.slice(9, 20);

            var tblRows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + v.title + "</td>" + "<td>" + 0 + '  ₹' + "</td>" + "<td>" + datee + "</td>" + "<td>" + timee + "</td>" + "<td><a target='_blank' href='" + str + "'>" + "WATCH/DOWNLOAD" + "</a></td>" + "</tr>";

            $(tblRows).appendTo("#userdata");
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two loops like this.

```
$.each(json.data.schedules, function (index, schedule) {
    $.each(schedule.liveVideoList, function (i, v) {
        var str = v.thumbnailUrl.split("vi/").pop();

        var datee = v.publishDate.slice(0, 9);
        var timee = v.publishDate.slice(9, 20);

        var tblRows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + v.title + "</td>" + "<td>" + 0 + '  ₹' + "</td>" + "<td>" + datee + "</td>" + "<td>" + timee + "</td>" + "<td><a target='_blank' href='" + str + "'>" + "WATCH/DOWNLOAD" + "</a></td>" + "</tr>";

        $(tblRows).appendTo("#userdata");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## A for..of loop

```
for (let schedule of json.data.schedules) {
    //Do something with schedule
}
```

## A for..in loop

```
for (let scheduleIndex in json.data.schedules) {
    //Do something with json.data.schedules[scheduleIndex]
}
```

## A for loop

```
for (let index = 0; index < json.data.schedules.length; index++) {
    //Do something with json.data.schedules[index]
}
```

## A while loop

```
var index = 0;
while (index < json.data.schedules.length) {
    //Do something with json.data.schedules[index]
    index++;
}
```